# how to save data into foriegn key in django

Tags: python, django

In my django project I have two models

Categoty and another is Lead

Category is a model from a third party app, which I am using.

```
class CustomerLeads(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    item_required = models.ForeignKey(Category,null=True, blank=True)
```

Views.py:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    name = request.POST['customername']
    item = request.POST['item']
    customer_lead_obj = CustomerLeads.objects.create(customer_name = name)
    customer_lead_obj.item_required = item
    customer_lead_obj.save()
```

When I want to save, an error comes:

```
Cannot assign "u'Saari'": "CustomerLeads.item_required" must be a "Category" instance.
```

Here, saari is a value which I get when I post the form.

Comment: Why aren't you using Django forms for this?

Comment: i am using html forms

Comment: That didn't answer the question. Django forms output HTML forms but also take care of validation and type conversion.

Comment: @vikrantVerma show your `Category` model in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear that `request.POST['item']` is not a `Category` instance, you need to read a category instance from your database based on `request.POST['item']`

You may do:

```
item = request.POST['item']
cat = Category.objects.get(item=item)  # if Category has item field
```

Now, you can use `cat` like this:

```
customer_lead_obj.item_required = cat
```

If `item` is not unique, you will need to pass an attribue that you can use to identify your category. Instead of `item` you can pass for example `cat_id`, something like:

```
cat_id = request.POST['cat_id']
cat = Category.objects.get(id=cat_id)  # or (pk=cat_id)
# ...
customer_lead_obj.item_required = cat
```

Comment: i cant understand.please elabrate

Comment: Take a look at the example added above, I think it should be clear now :)

Comment: @vikrantVerma, the type() of the request.POST['item'] is not a Category.

Comment: it shows me a error `get() returned more than one Category -- it returned 2!`

Comment: So in your form you need to pass something that identifies your Category if item is not unique.